# Extracting Disqus comments using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape, disqus

I want to scrape disqus comments but it does not appear since it is on iframe I did search online but some were using other languages or API requiring public and secret key is there a way to do it with python?

I am using bs4 and python requests
this is my current code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import MySQLdb


headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'kolnovel.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/???? Safari/537.36'
}
data = {
    'sitekey': '6LczjqQeAAAAAPZAEeL8qpc8-Hgi0iPVpD6ZSR-u',
    'token': '03AIIukzh0JOVba9CKdlX0NvOZwbzNzDfvlQ2f2ZeCY5DF6HMIFOihWbqEUtmrlrQ3vDGPx8EuCO3wls1q2m-Z9uFOSIDeoIDOiG4QOsv0S2ceL4JX9WrQFO2ZI7my97ZTWCS3rmn9CjNxZOmreEJX2PzDnRzjfCBqMfiMLvYbZ8QiW-04-HPsy_E0nbiGSbO7OYHGungumE4eE-Glt2mi9jiwqXsDvVPozZSWPrXcv4jGAQeRaTUdp1SbkFYdImB-EoO2YOahmQGtQ5WUGYeGiviuq0FDAQxsSXDRq4fzgSyBkYI4njRnOSX6eIHrYcQUNyEUL6s2xsoF2bX68rJ42xxcER83u9O3mb1Y4Yckgjbo0mfzbk7JBn5gi1bOYG5MzE05BLeEh5J_3fvdD1A72TP5bxjzgSN56fzg9UhCg2tYYVt6dW1h31_l9hXLJMD9-kztZIm72Xlj0cHOUsJH8JFgxeQhDbTYvp_sv5kplPvOHh3U2HEsC1d9U9lHwWUF7U1NAPABmF_JarsasrOhbFtefarcpynFf4XFYL4dveA3IpfSjMI2x2-pXEOOFLEYjiDmdTOHnJRrSoVuekENfVRc5pctQamv8A',
    'recaptcha_for_all_button': ''
}


link = 'https://kolnovel.com/swallowed-star-75403/'
html_text = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
postJson = json.loads(requests.get(soup.find_all('link')[7]['href'], headers=headers).text)
next = soup.find_all('a')[16]['href']
```

and this is the link I am trying to scrape
https://kolnovel.com/swallowed-star-76124/

this is some related data not sure if it would help

this.page.url = "https://kolnovel.com/swallowed-star-76124/";
this.page.identifier = "76124 [https://kolnovel.com/?p=76124";](https://kolnovel.com/?p=76124%22;)
this.page.title = "swallowed star 13";
s.src = 'https://https-rewayatthima-blogspot-com-eg.disqus.com/embed.js';

Comment: what is the url ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what are you using to scrape?

Comment: I have added more details please check now.

Comment: If they are in an iframe, they are most probable being dynamically loaded, as most of disqus comments are. You need to either follow the API call to get the comments or use selenium.

Comment: can you share me a link?